# Mathematical constants and approximations of irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, recreational-mathematics, real-numbers, floating-point

I found two examples where various constants have some surprising properties, related to the approximations of real numbers (you can convince yourself with Wolfram Alpha):

> The real number $\pi^{\pi^{1/\pi}}\approx5.19644$ has the same first $\lfloor \pi \rfloor$ decimals as the number $3\sqrt{\lfloor \pi\rfloor}\approx5.19615$. If we replace $\pi$ with $e$ in the above phrase, we get the same result: $e^{e^{1/e}}\approx4.24044$, $3\sqrt{\lfloor 
>  e\rfloor}\approx4.24264$.

> The Euler-Mascheroni constant, $\gamma\approx0.57721$, has the same first $3$ decimals as $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\approx0.57735$.

It is very unlikely that these examples do have a strong mathematical explanation, therefore they might be pure coincidence.

For the first one, it seems obvious that if I change the $100^{th}$ decimal of $\pi$, for example, the result still holds. Also, over a ,,small'' neighbourhood of $\pi$ or $e$, the result is verified.

Do you know other similar examples, where mathematical constants "almost" satisfy a short equation or appear in an unexpected way (I mean, not related to their usual definitions and applications)?

You are more than welcome to post an answer, your effort will be appreciated!

P.S. This question is mainly **recreational** and is the result of my pure imagination.

Comment: Please use mathjax. Also review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Comment: Are you asking about $\pi^{\sqrt[\pi]{\pi}}$ vs $\sqrt {9\pi}$?  But those numbers are ${5.19645, 5.31736}$ respectively.  See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5E%28pi%5E%281%2Fpi%29%29%2C+sqrt%289pi%29)

Comment: The problem is not the layout. But according to lulu, the claim is just false.

Comment: What was the source of this statement maybe that can make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I corrected the post

Comment: @lulu The OP's second number has a floor part in it. So it is $3 \sqrt{3}=5.19615...$ and so *does* hqve the same first $3$ [i.e. floor of $\pi$ ] digits as the first number mentioned in post.

Comment: Note also when $\pi$ is replaced by $e$ the first number OP mentions is $e^(e^(1/e))=4.2404..$ and matches the first $2=floor(e)$ digits of the number $3 \sqrt{2}=4.2426....$ [In this and the last comment I mean digits after the decimal point]

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for confirmation, this is why I am asking.

Comment: @PaulRebenciuc Yes I was surprised as well. Any other numbers it works on? [+1 on question...]

Comment: As one can see from a graph, there are exactly two positive solutions to $x^{x^{1/x}} = 3\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}$. It is a cool coincidence that those two solutions are super close to $e$ and $\pi$, but it is (in my opinion) merely a meaningless coincidence.

Comment: I agree with Greg Martin in that it's just a coincidence. If you look at the roots of complicated functions that you yourself can mess around with, at some point, there's going to be some coincidence like this that pops out to you. If you change it to $2\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ or some other variation, then the roots don't look as nice.

Comment: @GregMartin You are right, I have already checked this before posting this question. I know that the numbers involed in that equation does not have any relationship with the definitions of $\pi$ and $e$.

Comment: See this [nearest integer algorithm](https://ssodelta.wordpress.com/tag/almost-integer/)

Comment: $3+\frac {1}{7+\frac {1}{16}}=3.14159292...$ and $\pi=3.14159265...$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example of
$$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$$
is [rather famous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication#Sample_consequence).

Comment: The late Martin Gardiner used to write a monthly article "Mathematical Recreations" for Scientific American. One April article was all April Fools, and included the assertion that $e^{\pi\sqrt {163}}$ had been shown to be an integer. (The Gelfond-Schneider Theorem actually implies it is transcendental.)

Answer (score 2):

Today I found :

$$e^{e^{\frac{1}{e^{2}}}}>\pi$$

Edit 01/01/2022

Another one for the new year :

### $$e^{\frac{2\left(\pi^{2}-e^{2}\right)}{\pi^{2}+e^{2}}}<\frac{4}{3}$$

Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 1):

Guess what? $$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\approx\pi$$
This approximation is good to two decimal places. I know there is some mathematical intuition behind [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvQ-EZw7AQ8) but the fact it is correct to two decimal places is probably coincidence.

I made this approximation of $\pi$ using desmos: $$\sqrt[11]{294204}\approx\pi$$ Which is correct to seven digits.

Comment: Thanks for your example/video!

Comment: @PaulRebenciuc your welcome. Take a look at the other approximation.